# What's "the Drupal way" to do this (dynamic content in a Page)?

Tags: drupal

This is a follow up question of [How to get URL argument in Page body by PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744746/how-to-get-url-argument-in-page-body-by-php/) .

Objective: Site content editor needs to show dynamic content, based on a URL parameter, i.e.:

URL:

```
http://example.com/node/1?Name=John
```

In Page node:

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['Name'])) { ?>

  <?php print "Dear " . $_GET['Name'] . ","; ?>

<?php } else { ?>

  Hello,

<?php } ?>

   blah blah blah ...
```

You may imagine the URL is from a link inside an EDM message. Both the EDM message and the Page content is maintained by the same content editor.

So, what is *the Drupal way* to archive this?

Comment: whats an EDM message? Why is it relevent that both the content and the message are authored by the same person? Are you trying to ge the name of the author to display in the node body?

Comment: EDM - Email Direct Marketing. Editor (presumably) knows very little PHP. If possible, programmers should help to minimize the need to use PHP inside content.

Comment: I'm still confused as to what the question is. . . from your snippet it looks like you got it handled. Drupal doesn't really have an api for dealing with the _GET outside of the arg() and menu functions etc. If you'd like to see a drupal module that passes info to a node edit using get check out groups.

Comment: @mirzu, please check out the background of this question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744746/how-to-get-url-argument-in-page-body-by-php/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a module that extends the functionality of the token module to allow for the use of the various _GET variables as tokens in the body. The code to make the tokens available isn't a big deal, and using the token filter module below would make it simple for the editor to use the values in the node body.

http://drupal.org/project/token_filter

Comment: You can also use http://drupal.org/project/token_custom to create your tokens from GET parameters (don't forget to validate and filter them). Creating a custom module is, imho, preferred but token_custom can provide some help when prototyping.