# Drupal 7 insted of $_GET

Tags: drupal, get

i use drupal 7 for my site and i like to get variable from my url.
For example https://test.com/drupal/?var1=test.
In php we use $_GET['var1'] and it's ok, how wedo it in drupal 7 ? Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744746/how-to-get-url-argument-in-page-body-by-php

Answer (score 1):

```
$params = drupal_get_query_parameters();
if (isset($params['var1']) {
  var_dump(check_plain($params['var1']));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use arg() function and pass the index of parameter to get variable from URL in Drupal 7.